# can Lucene be used to search inside db?

Tags: java, database, search, lucene

Can we use Lucene to search text stored in DB?
I saw this article that shows how to  use it for normal articles stored as files
http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/

Can someone suggest?

Comment: Is it MySQL or isn't it?  Any such solution is going to be dependent on the specific database type.

Comment: @skaffman: No it isn't. If the indexing is done externally - with Lucene, say - then it can be done in a database-independent way. For example, the link in Pangea's answer indicates how to do it by hand (creating Lucene documents), and points to tools which automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the below question from [their FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_use_Lucene_to_index_a_database.3F). If you are using Hibernate then I recommend you to consider [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html).

**How can I use Lucene to index a database?**

Comment: Thanks.Can it be used with JPA when hibernate is used as provider

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Compass Framework](http://www.compass-project.org/). It's built upon Lucene and [integrates nicely with several ORMs](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/html/introduction.html#i-use-orm)

Update: you should now use [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) instead (thanks Pangea)

Comment: Compass framework is no longer in support. ElasticSearch is the new project started by the creator of compass.

Comment: Does Elastic Search have a JDBC store?

Comment: The guy's [blog post](http://www.kimchy.org/the_future_of_compass/) doesn't say that Compass is dead, it says Compass is in maintenance mode. And it's quite clear about the fact that ElasticSearch is *not* a Compass replacement - one of the things it lacks is precisely the ORM integration that would make it useful for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use Lucene to search text stored in DB?

Yes, you can. Lucene is able to read different kind of database-tables (like mysql,etc). In order to search stored text in an DB, lucene needs to index all the data you like to search.
But don't forgett: lucene is just an index. To access lucene - that mens to search inseide or to start import (whatever) you need an 2nd part oft software, to "use" (control,...) the data inside lucene.
This could be solr, for example http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

On the RDBMS you don't need an fulltext index for that anymore.